# No definition of XMLHttpRequest was found nodejs saving in parse.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am trying to save a object in parse.com with the following code.

```
localStorage = require('localStorage');
XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

Parse.initialize(APP_ID, JAVASCRIPT_KEY);

var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();

gameScore.set("score", 1337);
gameScore.set("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.set("cheatMode", false);

gameScore.save(null, {
    success: function(gameScore) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + gameScore.id);
    },
    error: function(gameScore, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
    }
});
```

But when I try this I get the following error message on the page.

*Error: Cannot make a request: No definition of XMLHttpRequest was found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove .XMLHttpRequest from require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest; so it should be

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And install npm install xmlhttprequest before using it.

Use xhr wherever you want to use it.

Or use http

```
var http = require('http');
```

You do not need to install it as it comes default with node

Comment: @user3765430 have you installed l xmlhttprequest before using it

Comment: I have tried the following: 

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

But i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: yes i have installed it. using npm install xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

To make http requests using Parse SDK, use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()` instead

Comment: I have tried the following: 

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

But i am still receiving the same error.